# Issue with jax.lax.scan

Tags: python, jax

I am supposed to use Jax.lax.scan instead of a for loop with 100 iterations at line 22. I am supposed to update S and append it to S_list. I am unsure how to fix the jax.lax.scan. The error that keeps popping up is missing the required XS. When I put a value for XS it says that my length argument doesn't line up with the axis sizes. Here is my code. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling scan with the correct signature. You can find more information on the call signature in the [`jax.lax.scan` docs](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.scan.html). It makes clear, for example, that your `step` function must accept two arguments and return two arguments.

From looking at your code, it looks like you're intending to do something like this:

```py
@jax.jit
def simulate():
  key = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)
  def step(S, _):
    dZ = jax.random.normal(key, shape=(S.size,)) * jnp.sqrt(dt)
    dS = r * S  * dt + σ  * S  * dZ
    return S + dS, S
  S0 = jnp.ones(20000)
  _, S_array = jax.lax.scan(step, S0, xs=None, length=m)
  return S_array
```

In particular, from the docs you can see that the `S_list.append(...)` and `S_array = jnp.stack(S_list)` are effectively part of the `scan` function itself, so you don't have to do that yourself after calling it.

Hope that helps!